# How can I use an imputing class to replace a value with the one on the row above?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imputation

I have the following dataframe:

```
|1|2|3|
------
|4|-999|6|
------
|7|8|9|
```

I want to replace the only the -999 value with the value from the previous row, same column. In this case the value is 2 and the dataframe would look like this:

```
|1|2|3|
-
|4|2|6|
-
|7|8|9|
-
```

I can do this using an iterative structure, but I think one of the imputing classes is better. My first choice would be `KNNImputer`, but, although it says that it uses values from the k-Nearest neighbors [source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html), I don't know if it can take the value from *that* neighbor.

So, how can I solve this problem? Is an imputer class a good idea? Or there is a better one?

Comment: Is it always the value -999 you want to replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest setting the value (-999) to `np.nan` and then use [fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with
`method='ffill'`. It propagates the last-valid value to the NA values.

Note, if the first element in each column is `np.nan` it is not filled (since there is no value before it to propagate)